# How to share cookies between domain and subdomain with nookies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm using [nookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies) and I'm having a hard time sharing cookies between my app and website.

This is the code I use on my app.mydomain.com file:

```
       //setCookies to main domain
        setCookie(null, 'jwt', loginResponse.jwt, {
          maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
          path: '/',
          domain: 'mydomain.com'
        });
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong since it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out because my main domain had www before the domain, it didn't work but now it's working since I removed it.